# Align items in css

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Currently when I have my window at full width my items appear like so:
[image]

When I make the window smaller the Submit button moves up.[image]

How would I be able to set it to stay evenly centered?

Here is my code:

```
<form>
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-sm-3">
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <div className="col-sm-3">
      <label>
        Phone:
        <input type="text" name="name" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <div className="col-sm-3">
      <label>
        Email:
        <input type="text" name="name" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <div className="col-sm-3">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is in a react component that is why it's `className`.

Comment: show complete code with css

Comment: Did you inspect your code from broswer to check why happen this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either...

1. [Flex Box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and `justify-content: space-between`;
2. [Css grids](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);`